# android phonegap custom "Web page not found"

Tags: android, cordova

Problem:
I'm trying to avoid the "**web page not found**", or at least to display a customized error page.

Context:

I use the `cordova` trick:

```
if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) 
{
    window.location="offline/index.html";
} 
else 
{
    window.location="http://myurl.com";
}
```

But in my tablet, if there's no connection, I have the ugly  "WebPage not found".

There's maybe something wrong in my code, but in all case I would like to find a way to avoid this page and to show my own.

I will be very happy if somebody here can tell me where to give a look.

Stef

PS : the "Page Not found" appears when the website is down. It's not related to the event offline. You can have internet, and the server can be down. In that case, I want to display my own error page. Thanks!

Comment: Wen this code is called after or before deviceready?

Comment: Hi Divesh. The code is called onload => ondeviceready
(cannot format code here))

Comment: I have executed the code without using function onload its working fine... CHeck whether your path to the file is correct.

Comment: Hi divesh.
Sometimes the website can be down... In that case there's the page "website not available" in black and white. It is this page I want to replace.

Comment: In offline your referring to local file rgt ? den der wont be any issue related to website not avaliable

Comment: It's the default system page when an url cannot be found. It says: ---------------------
Webpage not available

The webpage at http://myurl.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Suggestions:etc, etc....
---------- try to go to www.dyhfdh.com in Chrome, you should have the same page.

Comment: You can have internet, and the server can be down. In that case, I want to display my own error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event `offline` available in Cordova. You could add event listeners to this and do required changes in its callback. If you are using `deviceready` event it will be called only once when your app is done loading. But if you add `offline` & `online` listeners you can alert user each time network goes down/up.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
}
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

Comment: Hi 2-Stroker. Thanks for that one.

But in case the page is down, there's the page "website not available" in black and white. It is this page I want to replace. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @user2598413 You can redirect user to static page in the event listener.

Comment: hi 2-stroker, can you develop your answer please? It sounds very interesting :)

Comment: You can have internet, and the server can be down. In that case, I want to display my own error page.

Comment: ok, let's say we have the answer for the no connection case. I will open a new ticket for the "web page not found" when there is connection but when the server is down.